# Есть запрос к MySQL, нужно сделать через JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

Есть запрос

```
SELECT * FROM  
(SELECT id FROM shop_product WHERE type_id = 4 OR type_id = 2 OR type_id = 3) t1   
LEFT JOIN   
(SELECT product_id FROM features WHERE cou_id = 18) t2   
ON t1.id = t2.product_id WHERE t2.product_id IS NULL
```

Нужно сделать через JOIN, без 3х SELECT, только 1 SELECT

Comment: Хорошо было бы увидеть пример с набором данных и что должен в результате отобразить запрос после выполнения.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.id FROM shop_product as t1 
LEFT JOIN features as t2 on t1.id= t2.t2.product_id 
WHERE 
  (t1.type_id = 4 OR t1.type_id = 2 OR t1.type_id = 3) 
   and t2.product_id IS NULL
```

Данные подставьте, какие Вам надо.
 Если Вы хотите исключить записи, то надо делать по другому ....`NOT IN (SELECT....)` Опишите лучше подробнее, что конкретно Вы хотите вывести...

Comment: Вы правы, я костылей наделал ....NOT IN (SELECT....)  подходит

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.* 
FROM shop_product t1
LEFT JOIN features t2 ON t2.product_id = t1.id
WHERE 
    (t1.type_id = 4 OR t1.type_id = 2 OR t1.type_id = 3) 
    AND t2.cou_id = 18 
    AND t2.product_id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Если 
 (t1.type_id = 4 OR t1.type_id = 2 OR t1.type_id = 3)   AND t2.cou_id = 18 
все работает правильно, показывает 1 товар что есть в 2х таблицах
но когда добавляю 
t2.product_id IS NULL;
ничего не находит.
Как вы поняли, мне нужен список всех записи что есть в t1.id и нету в t2.product_id

Comment: попробуйте inner join запрос и действительно ли у Вас Null t2.product_id?

Comment: нельзя использовать LEFT, потому и не работало.. но по правилам движка нельзя использовать.. как єто можно обойти ?

Answer (score 1):

Данное условие:

```
ON t1.id = t2.product_id WHERE t2.product_id IS NULL
```

никогда не будет выполнено, потому что `t2.product_id` не может одновременно быть `NULL` и чему-либо равняться. `NULL` ничему не может быть равен. Так что из второй таблицы никаких значений получено не будет.

Может быть, вы хотели получить товары из таблицы `shop_product`, для которых нет соответствий в таблице `features`?

```
SELECT * FROM shop_product AS p
LEFT JOIN features AS f
  ON f.cou_id = 18 AND p.id = f.product_id
WHERE p.type_id IN (2, 3, 4) AND f.product_id IS NULL
```